# Is there a way to handle close/collapse events in Accordion in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, accordion

Is there a way to handle close/collapse events in Accordion in Angularjs?

I need to clear filters on close/collapse in Accordion in Angularjs.

Comment: AngularJS doesn't have an accordion. Which library containing an accordion are you using? Or did you implement it by yourself? If so, how?

Comment: Using bootstrap with ui-bootstrap.js. I used 'is-open' to check and set certain values for open and close events. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using bootstrap, and hence you can follow documentation from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

There is an example on toggling the accordion elements individually using a is-open="status.open" in the accordion group (this example also has chevron linked to the same status):

```
<accordion-group is-open="status.open">
    <accordion-heading>
        I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
    This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
</accordion-group>
```

And then you can control dynamically the accordion status via $scope.status.open toggling it between true and false. And just remember to make sure you don't have "close-others" -attribute set...

Comment: Thanks Antti. Yes, I am using bootstrap with ui-bootstrap.js and Angularjs. That's what I did now. Used 'is-open' to check and set variables. Works now!